# Excel Macro finds "BLOCKED" in all the rows of all the columns cell by cell

Tags: vba, excel

In this small part of the code, although the condition gets set to true, it goes to the `Else` statement.

```
Sub check()  
    Dim temp As Integer  
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select     
    For j = 18 To 29     
        For i = 2 To 39          
            If Cells(i, j).Value = "BLOCKED" Then     
                temp = temp + 1     
            Else     
                temp = 0     
            End If     
        Next     
        MsgBox temp     
    Next 
End Sub
```

Though BLOCKED is present in the Excel sheet in which I am running this macro, it doesn't return true.

Please help me find the error in what I am doing.

Comment: try adding a debug line before the `If` , `Debug.Print Cells(i, j).Value` , then also add `Debug.Print Cells(i, j).Value2` , see what you are getting in both cases

Comment: In any way, try to avoid using `Sheets("Sheet1").Select`, instead you can add `With Sheets("Sheet1")` before the first `For` loop

Comment: It may help if you include in your question an image of cells `R2:AC39` of your sheet.  That will help us determine whether it is failing due to the sheet containing `" BLOCKED"`, or `"BLOCKED "`, or `"blocked"`, or some other similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you haven't actually stepped through your code, but that you are just saying that "it goes to Else" because the `MsgBox` is displaying `0`, which it will currently do (unless the last cell in any column is not "BLOCKED") because you are resetting the value of `temp` every time you find a cell that is not "BLOCKED".

Try these changes to your code and see if they give the answer you expect.

Version which counts up how many times "BLOCKED" exists in each column:

```
Sub check()  
    Dim temp As Integer  
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For j = 18 To 29     
            temp = 0     
            For i = 2 To 39          
                If .Cells(i, j).Value = "BLOCKED" Then     
                    temp = temp + 1     
                End If     
            Next     
            MsgBox temp & " cell" & IIf(temp = 1, "", "s") & " in column " & j & IIf(temp = 1, " is", " are") & " 'BLOCKED'"
        Next 
    End With
End Sub
```

Version which counts up how many times "BLOCKED" exists in the entire area:

```
Sub check()  
    Dim temp As Integer  
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        temp = 0     
        For j = 18 To 29     
            For i = 2 To 39          
                If .Cells(i, j).Value = "BLOCKED" Then     
                    temp = temp + 1     
                End If     
            Next     
        Next 
        MsgBox temp & " cell" & IIf(temp = 1, "", "s") & " in entire area " & IIf(temp = 1, " is", " are") & " 'BLOCKED'"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is an additional whitespace in the "BLOCKED" cell. Also try getting the Text of the Cell with

```
If Cells(i, j).Text= "BLOCKED" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens that "BLOCKED" is not exactly the content of a cell.
You might want to try this.

```
If instr(1, Cells(i, j), "BLOCKED")>0  Then
```

Hope it helps.